# Visual C++: checked list box doesn't clear

Tags: visual-c++, checkedlistbox

I'm writing a quite simple VCpp program. On the form1 I've put a 'checkedListBox1', where
I can make selections.

Every time, that I press the 'botton1', these selections should be cleared.

So while I'm writing the code, I click twice on the botton to get into the event.
The first instruction, that now isn't important, works fine.

Then I write:

```
checkedListBox1->ClearSelected();
```

The intellisense says, that this method should clear all selections, but it doesn't.
When I'm running the program, after selecting 1 of 4 possibilities in the box, and
clicking on the botton1, the selections still remain.

I'm sure to have forgotten something. Somebody could give me an' idea?

I'm working with Visual C++ 2008, Express Version.

Thanks and regards

Uwe_98

Answer (score 0):

Selected items are not the same thing as checked items. Selected means you have a (usually blue) highlight on the item and checked means the checkbox is ticked.

To clear all the checkmarks, you have to use the [`SetItemChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemchecked.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) method rather than [`ClearSelected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.clearselected.aspx) which is actually inherited from `ListBox` and has nothing to do with check boxes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1->Items->Count; ++i)
{
    checkedListBox1->SetItemChecked(i, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works fine. Now I've discovered another problem: The box allows me to check various Items. Is there a property that allows me to check just one Item?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Uwe_98 ok but rather than stringing these problems on the original question it's better to accept this answer and post a separate question for your new problem.